# jQuery for edit doesn't work on AJAX loaded page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, ready

I'm new in AJAX and jQuery, I try to use jQuery for my edit page. When this file is executed on direct page like `localhost/test/test_edit.php` it works perfectly, but it doesn't work in AJAX loaded page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".editlink").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
    var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
    var theid   = dataset.attr("id");
    var newid   = theid+"-form";
    var currval = dataset.text();

    dataset.empty();

    $('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">').appendTo(dataset);

    $(this).css("display", "none");
});
});



<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="core">
        <div class="profileinfo">               
            <div class="gear">
                <label>Full Name:</label>
                <span id="fullname" class="datainfo">Johnny Appleseed</span>
                <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the click part of your code in the complete section of your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    complete : funnction(){
        editLinkClick();
    },
    ...
});
```

And have this as a function you can call on the initial page load and in the complete of your ajax page load:

```
function editLinkClick() {
    $(".editlink").off('click').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
        var savebtn = $(this).next(".savebtn");
        var theid   = dataset.attr("id");
        var newid   = theid+"-form";
        var currval = dataset.text();

        dataset.empty();

        $('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">').appendTo(dataset);

        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't know where is $.ajax({... 
on this part?
function getRequest() {
    var req = false;
    try{
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return req;
}